How to achieve advanced autocompletion in React CodeMirror?
I'm trying to implement a code editor on my react site, I need to implement a pretty good autocompletion for Python. I ran into a problem, which is that I haven't figured out how to add some ready-made solutions here (to be honest, I haven't even found any yet). Speaking of my own attempts, I tried to solve this by adding my provider: autocompletion({ override: [customCompletionProvider] }),.
Also its code:

    const customCompletionProvider = (context) => {
      const word = context.matchBefore(/\w*/);
    
      const code = context.state.doc.toString();
    
      // detect variables in code
      const variableDeclarationPattern = /(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+)/g;
      let match;
      while ((match = variableDeclarationPattern.exec(code)) !== null) {
        const [_, varName, varValue] = match;
        if (/['"]/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "str";
        else if (/\[.*\]/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "list";
        else if (/\(.*\)/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "tuple";
        else if (/\{.*\}/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "dict";
        else if (/[-+]?\d+/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "int";
        else if (/[-+]?\d*\.\d+/.test(varValue)) variables[varName] = "float";
      }
    
      // method call through dot? =>
      const dotMatch = context.matchBefore(/\w+\.\w*/);
      if (dotMatch) {
        const [variable, methodStart] = dotMatch.text.split(".");
    
        if (variables[variable]) {
          const methods = getMethodsForType(variables[variable]);
          return {
            from: dotMatch.from + variable.length + 1,
            options: methods.map((method) => ({
              label: method,
              type: "method",
            })),
          };
        }
      }
    
      const letterMatch = context.matchBefore(/[a-z]|[A-Z]/);
      console.log(letterMatch);
    
      if (!letterMatch) {
        return null;
      }
    
      const basicSuggestions = [
        { label: "print", type: "function" },
        { label: "len", type: "function" },
        { label: "str", type: "type" },
        { label: "int", type: "type" },
        { label: "list", type: "type" },
        { label: "dict", type: "type" },
        { label: "tuple", type: "type" },
        { label: "def", type: "function" },
        { label: "class", type: "class" },
        { label: "async", type: "keyword" },
        { label: "return", type: "keyword" },
        { label: "yield", type: "keyword" },
      ];
    
      return {
        from: word.from,
        options: basicSuggestions.filter((suggestion) =>
          suggestion.label.startsWith(word.text)
        ),
      };
    };


Besides the fact that my version doesn't work very well, to put it mildly, it also overrides the basic autocompletion, which I wouldn't want to lose.
Also code of component:

    <CodeMirror
      value={value}
      height="330px"
      width="1000px"
      extensions={[
        python(),
        indentUnit.of("    "),
        autocompletion({ override: [customCompletionProvider] }),
        onUpdateExtension,
      ]}
      onChange={onChange}
      theme={Theme}
    />;


Also i'm using onUpdateExtension:

    const onUpdateExtension = EditorView.updateListener.of((update) => {
      if (update.docChanged) {
        const { state } = update.view;
        const doc = state.doc.toString();
        const lastChar = doc[doc.length - 1];
    
        if (lastChar === ".") {
          startCompletion(update.view);
        }
      }
    });


PS: my main goal is to add hints for variable methods, right after typing the dot
